# Is this an example of limited floating point precision in WebGL shaders?

Tags: floating-point, glsl, webgl, shader

I have an [example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3ljGWD) shader on shadertoy which isn't behaving as I expected. It takes X and Y fragment coordinates, adds them together, calculates the [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of this expression. The ULP value is expected to be very small, so I multiply it by a very large number and output that as the pixel color. I would expect white pixels, but I get black, indicating that the value was actually zero. Is this some kind of error cause by precision limitations in my WebGL implementation (Google Chrome for Windows)?

```
float ulp(float f)
{
    int i = floatBitsToInt(f);
    return abs(intBitsToFloat(i + 1) - f);
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    float f = fragCoord.y + fragCoord.x;
    vec3 col = vec3(ulp(f) * 3.4e38);
    fragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

**EDIT:** Out of curiosity I loaded up the shadertoy example on my phone and lo and behold I got a white screen as I had originally expected.

Comment: Are you sure `floatBitsToInt` is the function you want to use? What exactly do you mean by adding 1 to the integer resulting from this conversion? Are you sure that this will affect the floating-point representation in the way you would like? Because I think it would add 1 to the exponent of the float.

Comment: @NicolBolas Reinterpreting a float as an int and adding one produces the next largest float. It is equivalent of std::nextafter. You can see it in action here. https://repl.it/repls/SmoggyDimpledPrinters

Comment: does section 4.5.1 of the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf) answer your question?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Maybe you only have a WebGL 1.0 compatible browser?

Comment: @gman Not really. I says that highp floats use the IEEE 754 format, and it says that operations like addition are correctly rounded. If that was the case then I would expect it to work. Out of curiosity I loaded up the shadertoy example on my phone and lo and behold I got a white screen as I had originally expected.

Comment: @Chris_F: Thanks. Safari 12 supports WebGL 2.0, but only if it is enabled in the “Experimental Features”. I turned it on, and the resulting display is white, not black as the question reports.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Since it works on Safari (assuming Mac?) and my Android phone, but doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome for Windows, I assume that this may be a bug with OpenGL ES 3.0 support on Windows.

Comment: @Chris_F: I would consider it a likely hypothesis, and I would tinker with other expressions to experiment. E.g., change the color to 1 if ulp(f) is any non-zero value and 0 otherwise, and see what the results are. (Of course, if you have any direct way to report the value of ulp(f), I would do that.) Test whether the coloring breaks if the color number is very very large—maybe 3.4e38 is breaking something.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, Safari doesn't even remotely support WebGL2. [Every WebGL2 API entry point is *NOT IMPLEMENTED" as of 2019/12/29](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/html/canvas/WebGL2RenderingContext.cpp). The only thing Safari currently does when you enable WebGL2 is respond to getContext when passed webgl2 and allow GLSL ES 3.0 shaders. That's it. All other funcftionality is unimplemented.